# include slashes in the URL for htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite rules in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

on index.php i have `echo $_GET["id"];`

it works fine, so `domain.com/services` rewrites to `domain.com/index.php?id=services`however if i visit

```
domain.com/services/service1
```

the echoed variable is showing `404.shtml`

what rule would i need to allow slashes?

Comment: What would you expect? That the id is empty or that it has service1?

Comment: maybe i should have been more specific! check my update

Comment: the ID should be id=services/service1

Comment: So you want id to be services/service1? You should put the **exact** string you expect the id to be in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. You had set your rule to match anything **except** slashes. Just allow anything.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```